# In leaflet for R, I am unable to reproduce a standard example illustrating how icons work

Tags: r, url, hyperlink, leaflet, icons

This is one of the more common leaflet examples out there. But when I run this code, I do not see red and green leaf icons in the ocean or in my legend, I see blue squares with question marks. The background map is correct though.

```
library(leaflet)

# Sample Data
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

# Choose Icon:
leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
                   "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
                   "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>
<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png'>red"

# Produce Map:
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons) %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
```

Comment: I tried it and I get a legend with broken symbols and no markings of earthquake locations on the map. Searching for http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png gives error 404 (file not found) plus notes about finding it on github. Possibly error is due to file changing location without update to package.

Comment: Well, that was easy.

Comment: Did you find the new location of the files?

Comment: No, but since any icons will do, it was just a matter of swapping these for others.